# The behavior of fireflies model in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm looking closely at the behavior of the fireflies model in Models Library.

Recently, I thought that each firefly might be looking at the state of flashing of others one step before the current step.

The reason for this question is as follows: 
In go procedure, say at step t, each firefly increments its own clock (t + 1), then look at others' flashes if the focal firefly is not flashing at step t + 1. However, the state of others' flashes the focal firefly is looking at is still that in the step t.

Although this might not affect the global behavior of the model, I think this can allow fireflies to respond their own flashes.

I'd like to know whether this interpretation is correct or not.

(original go procedure)

```
to go
  ask turtles [
    move
    increment-clock
    if ( (clock > window) and (clock >= threshold) )
      [ look ]
  ]
  ask turtles [
    recolor
  ]
  tick
end
```

---

If my understanding is correct, the descriptions of the procedures go and look seem appropriate.

```
to go
  ask turtles [
    move
    increment-clock
  ]
  ask turtles [
    recolor
  ]  
  ask turtles [
    if ( (clock > window) and ((clock >= threshold) ))
      [ look ]
  ]
  tick
end

to look ; turtle procedure
  if count turtles in-radius 1 with [color = yellow] >= flashes-to-reset
    [ set clock (reset-level - 1)]
end
```

Comment: Interesting. Offhand, I'd agree it looks like a mistake. Hopefully someone will take a closer look.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Seth! I hope that this problem will be fixed in the future version of NetLogo Models Library (if I am correct), because this model is basic and important one showing synchronization behaviors.